# <rich:listShuttle> targetValue always empty

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have a rich listShuttle (richfaces 3.3 ) :

```
<rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{olapBackingBean.memberList}" 
                targetValue="#{olapBackingBean.selectedMemberList}" var="items"
                listsHeight="150" sourceListWidth="130" targetListWidth="130"
                sourceCaptionLabel="Members list"
                targetCaptionLabel="Selected Member">
                <rich:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{items}"></h:outputText>
                </rich:column>
                <a4j:support event="onlistchanged"  />
                <a4j:support event="onorderchanged" />
</rich:listShuttle>
```

My target value list is always empty, this is my backingBean :

```
public void setSelectedMemberList(List<String> selectedMemberList) {
        this.selectedMemberList = selectedMemberList;

}
public List<String> getSelectedMemberList() {
        return selectedMemberList;

}

public void setMemberList(List<String> memberList) {
    this.memberList = memberList;
}
public List<String> getMemberList() {
    return memberList;
}
```

My listShuttle is inside a modalPanel.

Comment: Just to make sure: you have this in a `h:form`, you have a `h:messages` (ajax-rendered) somewhere and it's not showing errors? Also, what's the scope of your backing bean?

Comment: thx for answering @mabi, yes I have this in a modal pannel in a separated h:form , I don't have a h:message, and my backing bean is view scooped.